# Set PKG_CONFIG_PATH inside meson.build

Tags: pkg-config, meson-build

I am using meson in a couple of C projects (`projectA` and `projectB`), where `projectB` links to a library from `projectA`. In `projectA/meson.build`, I have written a `pkg-config` `projectA.pc` file using meson, that is installed  to `join_paths(get_option('prefix'), get_option('libdir'), 'pkgconfig')` as expected.

In `projectB/meson.build` I use `dependency('projectA')` to look for the `projectA.pc` file.

When I use a custom installation prefix to build `projectA` and `projectB`, `meson` is unable to find `projectA.pc` when building `projectB`. Is there a way to specify a `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` from `projectB/meson.build`?

This issue is reproduce with this **minimal example**:

*projectA/meson.build:*

```
project('projectA', 'c', version: '1')

pkg = import('pkgconfig')

pkg.generate(name : 'projectA',
             description: 'ProjectA',
             version: meson.project_version())
```

*projectB/meson.build:*

```
project('projectB', 'c', version: '1')
dep = dependency('projectA')
```

Commands:

```
meson buildA projectA  --prefix=$PWD/install
(cd buildA && ninja install)
#[0/1] Installing files.
#Installing /tmp/test/buildA/meson-private/projectA.pc to /tmp/test/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig
# [ The error: ]
meson buildB projectB  --prefix=$PWD/install
#Native dependency 'projectA' not found
# [ My workaround: ]
PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$PWD/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig" meson buildB projectB  --prefix=$PWD/install
# Native dependency projectA found: YES 1
```

Is there a way to tell `projectB/meson.build` that `dependency()` should look into `join_paths(get_option('prefix'), get_option('libdir'), 'pkgconfig')`?

I was trying to have an environment variable set inside the meson `dependency()` call, but the `env` argument does not exist for `dependency()`:

```
pkgconfigpath = join_paths(get_option('prefix'), get_option('libdir'), 'pkgconfig')
message('pkgconfig: @0@'.format(pkgconfigpath))
env_pkgconfig = environment()
env_pkgconfig.set('PKG_CONFIG_PATH', pkgconfigpath)
projectA_dep = dependency('projectA', env: env_pkgconfig)
```

Unfortunately the `env:` argument in dependency is ignored (it does not exist in the docs).

Appending ${prefix}/${libdir}/pkgconfig directory to PKG_CONFIG_PATH from meson makes sense to me. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

After asking on the IRC, I was informed that `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` should be set by the user (not by me) so meson does not provide a way to change it.

The best approach in this case would be to use subprojects or wraps so meson handles everything at once.

Answer (score 1):

set `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` to wherever `projectA`'s `.pc` file is when you build `projectB`.

Yes, `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` is for users for sure.  However, in this context, whoever compiles your `projectA` and `projectB` is a user, even *you* are.

ie) When you want to compile `projectB` because you want to test `projectB` against new version of projectA which is installed to a different directory, then you must adjust the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`.

And Yes, it's much easier for your user if you setup `projectB` having `projectA` as a [subproject](http://mesonbuild.com/Subprojects.html).